# How do I find files that are checked out?

Tags: 2016

We are moving data from sharepoint to Google Drive and many files are checked out and can't be moved over. We need to find all the checked out files. How do we do this?

Comment: Where are you moving from? A single library, a single site collection or a complex multiple web application / site collections design? Are you allowed to use PowerShell?

Comment: Moving from several libraries. Do not have PowerShell. Just need to find the checked out files.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite common and one of the universal solutions is to run some PowerShell locally and retrieve a list of all such files. The problem you are facing is SharePoint hierarchical structure (Site Collection > Subsites > Document Libraries > Folders) and you would have to crawl up to the last level in order to make sure you got all the files.

You can find such a [script here](http://www.topsharepoint.com/list-all-checked-out-items-using-powershell), but as Mike points out in his comment in all depends what exactly you are moving out of SharePoint. In any case, it is a good start but will require some work.

Commercial tools like [SPDocKit](https://www.syskit.com/products/spdockit/) can also retrieve such reports. (Disclaimer: I am affiliated with this company)